# Angular Js event/listerner in factory service

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create service that listens to the a change in the browser window size and tells me if it is a phone or a tablet. I am using matchmedia-ng plugin to achieve this[matchmedia-ng](https://github.com/AnalogJ/matchmedia-ng). I have successfully got it working within the controller below.

However I would like to have it as a factory service so that I can use it in other controllers. I have been unsuccesful at this, can anyone help me? Note it is the var deviceListernerPhone, deviceListernerTablet and deviceListerDesktop within the loginCtrl that I would like to put in a service factory.

My coding is below for the html partial and ctrl is below:

**partial-login.html**

```
<ng-include src="deviceView()"></ng-include>
```

**loginCtrl**

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope','loginService','matchmedia', function($scope,loginService,matchmedia){
        $scope.login = function(){
        loginService.login (this.user); 
        }

   var deviceListernerPhone = matchmedia.onPhone(function(mediaQueryList){
            $scope.isPhone= mediaQueryList.matches;
        })

   var deviceListernerTablet = matchmedia.onTablet(function(mediaQueryList){
            $scope.isTablet= mediaQueryList.matches;
        })

   var deviceListernerDesktop = matchmedia.onDesktop(function(mediaQueryList){
            $scope.isDesktop= mediaQueryList.matches;
        })


   $scope.deviceView= function(){
    if ($scope.isPhone){
        return 'partials/login/tpl/login-phone.html';
    } else if($scope.isTablet){
        return 'partials/login/tpl/login-tablet.html';
    } else{
        return 'partials/login/tpl/login-desktop.html';
    }
   }//end deviceview 

}])
```

Comment: why there is `loginService.login (this.user); ` are you using `controllerAs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service which contains the media info can be like below:

```
app.service('MediaService',['matchmedia',function(matchmedia){
    var scope = this;
     matchmedia.onPhone(function(mediaQueryList){
            scope.isPhone= mediaQueryList.matches;
        });

   matchmedia.onTablet(function(mediaQueryList){
            scope.isTablet= mediaQueryList.matches;
        });

   matchmedia.onDesktop(function(mediaQueryList){
            scope.isDesktop= mediaQueryList.matches;
        });
}]);
```

and you shall inject it in your controller like:

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope','loginService','MediaService', function($scope,loginService,mediaService){
        $scope.login = function(){
        loginService.login (this.user); 
        }

   $scope.deviceView= function(){
    if (mediaService.isPhone){
        return 'partials/login/tpl/login-phone.html';
    } else if(mediaService.isTablet){
        return 'partials/login/tpl/login-tablet.html';
    } else{
        return 'partials/login/tpl/login-desktop.html';
    }
   }//end deviceview 

}]);
```

Comment: @pankajparkar It is just a precaution to set the isPhone , isTablet, isDesktop in the service scope and not the scope of the functions which set them.

Comment: @pankajparkar that is wrong, you are overwriting the matchmedia service which is injected in the service.

Comment: Thanks Manasi this is exactly what I was after and works a charm. Much appreciated for your efforts!

Comment: Also @pankajparkar in regards to your comment on why I was using this.user It was because I was using ng-include on the login html. The partials templates loaded are forms therefore created sub scope thus why I had to use this.

Comment: @pankajparkar , Ka Tech has already confirmed it. Well thanks for your thoughts though.

Comment: @KaTech Thats my bad, Actually i was confused with `matchmedia` & `MediaService` , manasi sorry for that with my wrong understanding..  +1 for good approach

Comment: @pankajparkar I also was confused by this, I think it is a  typo. In my code I actually change loginCtrl to:app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope','loginService','mediaService', function($scope,loginService,mediaService){

Answer (score 1):

You can structure your service, in a way so that it can accept matchmedia service's callbacks from controllers itself.

```
    app.service("matchMediaService", function(matchmedia) {

        this.registerCallbacks = function(onPhoneCallback, onPhoneCallback, onDesktopCallback) {
            matchmedia.onTablet = onPhoneCallback;
            matchmedia.onPhone = onPhoneCallback;
            matchmedia.onDesktop = onDesktopCallback;
        };

    });


    app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope','loginService','matchMediaService', function($scope,loginService,matchmedia){
        $scope.login = function(){
            loginService.login (this.user); 
        }

        $scope.onPhone = function(mediaQueryList){
            $scope.isPhone= mediaQueryList.matches;
        });


       $scope.onTablet = function(mediaQueryList){
            $scope.isTablet= mediaQueryList.matches;
       };

       $scope.onDesktop = function(mediaQueryList){
            $scope.isDesktop= mediaQueryList.matches;
        };

        matchMediaService.registerCallbacks($scope.onPhone, $scope.onTablet, $scope.onDesktop);

       $scope.deviceView= function(){
        if ($scope.isPhone){
            return 'partials/login/tpl/login-phone.html';
        } else if($scope.isTablet){
            return 'partials/login/tpl/login-tablet.html';
        } else{
            return 'partials/login/tpl/login-desktop.html';
        }
       }//end deviceview 

    }])
```

Comment: Hi Tech, thanks for your efforts. I did try this however could not get it working.

Comment: What was the issue ?? Can you elaborate on the "could not get it working part" ?? Also, i suggest adding a plunker for better visibility.